# Two consecutive points

Tags: geometry

Is there in math something like 2 consecutive points? I know that if 2 points are different then you can fit infinitely many points in the middle. Doesn't this mean then, that there is no such thing as 2 consecutive points?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "point."

Comment: Like points on a straight line

Comment: If you are talking Euclidean lines and real points, then no:  between $x$ and $y$ there is always $\frac{x+y}{2}$ (as long as $x \neq y$).  But if you were talking integer points on the line, then yes:  $x$ and $x+1$ are consecutive.

Comment: You can also talk about points verifying a certain property. For instance there are consecutive points on a polygon (property verified = they are summits). But anything "indexed" will also do.

Answer (score 0):

That dependes on what you are thinking about. If you consider for example natural or integers natumbers then speaking of consecutive points is correct, in fact we can say that $2$ is the consecutive of $1$ as $-9$ does for $-10$.

But when you talk about rational or real number this definition doesn't hold because, for example in $[0,1]$ there are more numbers than in $N$, so thinking about consecutive numbers is incorrect.

In Euclidean geometry, also, between two points we can find other infinite points, so there isn't a consecutive point for a fixed one.

Comment: @Anis Ndayisaba: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?